# Fill in the missing letters

Tags: pattern

Can you fill in the missing letters in the below sequence?

s,?,?,n,?,?,h,e

I have tried planets, periodic table, compass points, dates, months, days etc...

Please help!

I have been told by an administrator to say where this question came from, therefore it came from a quiz my girlfriend did at her University but was never given answers to.

Comment: Do you have any other context clues to go off of? Like what type of class was it? Something that could give more background as to why you think it is a representative sequence instead of a word.

Answer (score 2):

The only English word (that I could find) which fits the pattern is a rather uncommon one:

> [subniche](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subniche)

Comment: That seems like a word that would be applicable only in a narrow range of situations. Perhaps only in one part of a narrow range of situations.

Comment: I think the letters are more likely to represent words in a sequences (i.e. F,S,S,M,T,W,T being days of the week).

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer

> s, **y, s,** n, **r, s,** h, e

Reasoning

> Order the eight planets by their eccentricity 
>  Mercury 0.2056 
>  Mars    0.0934 
>  Saturn  0.0565  
>  Jupiter 0.0489  
>  Uranus  0.0464  
>  Earth   0.0167 
>  Neptune 0.0095  
>  Venus   0.0068 
>  Take the last letters of each entry to get the sequence **y, s, n, r, s, h, e, s** 
>  Rotate this sequence by one space to get **s, y, s, n, r, s, h, e**

Comment: I needed Earth for the *h*, though. Is there a different approach you were considering?

Comment: Ah, whoops. I misread -- my bad!

Comment: (Specifically, I thought the bolded letters were the fixed ones, not the ones you were filling in.)